# How to run before on most cypress tests but not all

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have a login test I want to code for cypress. Currently, I need to login before all tests so i use a before block. But I want to automatically run the login test before all tests except for 2 or 3 files. Is that possible? Or do I need to move the login code into the describe blocks themselves. I'd rather segment the tests because I don't want so much redundancy, writing the same code so many times.

Comment: In my experience It is best every test to have own setup and to login when needed as part of the `it`. That way you can be sure that the a possible fail is only due to it. not some other test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official Cypress documentation on hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Hooks) has a great example showing where `before` and `beforeEach` hooks are placed in the `describe` and `it` blocks, as well as outside of the `describe` block.

One thing they mention is to be wary of root level hooks, because of its unpredictable order of execution when running your specs together.

As far as I can see, you have a couple options here. 1) You can have your hooks explicitly stated in each of your spec files, so instead of having a root level login, you call that for each spec file that needs to run in. 2) You create a sort of base file where you can toggle whether the spec file will execute the login functionality.

But again, #2 may lead to some unpredictable behavior. My suggestion is to keep it simple and clean, and have your hooks specified directly in your spec files.

Comment: Thanks Kerry, I think I agree with you.